# Convert sql query to linq in C#

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-entities

Hi Could any one help how to write this below query in Linq C#

```
select YearValue from [Information].Year 
where YearId in (select max(YearId) from curreny where BudgetCodeId = 2)
```

Here's what I've tried:

```
var maxYear = 
    from year in dbContext.Years 
    join exchange in dbContext.CurrencyExchangeRates 
    on year.YearId equals exchange.YearId 
    where exchange.BudgetCodeId == budgetCodeId 
    orderby year.YearValue descending 
    select new { yearValue = year.YearValue };
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? SO isn't a code writing service.

Comment: i tried like this but am not getting desired output.  var maxYear =     from year in dbContext.Years
                                  join exchange in dbContext.CurrencyExchangeRates on year.YearId equals exchange.YearId
                                 where exchange.BudgetCodeId == budgetCodeId orderby year.YearValue descending 
                                  select new
                                  {
                                      yearValue = year.YearValue
                                  };

Comment: That doesn't really look anything like the SQL you're after. What is `CurrencyExchangeRates`? Why are you ordering by year value?

Comment: I want year value from year table where yearId taken from currencyexchangeRate table and that year id should be maximum

Comment: Have you heard of or tried looking at LinqPad. I find it quite useful for things like this.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you're looking for:

```
var maxYear = from year in dbContext.Years where (from exchange in dbContext.CurrencyExchangeRates where exchange.BudgetCodeId == 2 select exchange)
    .Max(m => m.YearId) == 
        year.YearId select year.YearValue;

int mYear = maxYear.First();
```